# Suppressing publisher in notes using biblatex-chicago

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, biblatex-chicago

Using `memoir`, `biblatex-chicago` in `notes` mode (compiled with `biber`), with "author-title" citations in the notes, is there a simple way to add a line that will cause all citations (in the notes and in the bibliography) to *omit the publisher*? That is, I would like it to be as if all `publisher` fields in the `.bib` file were empty.

## Update: MWE

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[notes]{biblatex-chicago}

\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@book{friedman1970orpheus,
    Address = {Cambridge, MA},
    Author = {Friedman, John Block},
    Publisher = {Harvard University Press},
    Shorttitle = {Orpheus},
    Title = {Orpheus in the {Middle} {Ages}},
    Year = {1970}}
\end{filecontents*}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}

Something about Orpheus.\footcite{friedman1970orpheus}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

I would like neither the footnote nor the bibliography entry under "References" to mention "Harvard University Press." Instead, the output in the footnote should be:

> John Block Friedman, *Orpheus in the Middle Ages* (Cambridge, MA, 1970).

And the output in the bibliography should be:

> Friedman, John Block. *Orpheus in the Middle Ages*. Cambridge, MA, 1970.

This would be the output if there were no `publisher` field in the `.bib` entry, but I would like to know if there is a way to do this automatically without deleting all information from `publisher` fields.

Comment: Please -- as usual here -- show us a short compilable tex code building your bibliography with an bib entry containing an publisher ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An alternative to [Paul Stanley](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/5404/paul-stanley)'s [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/468175/35864) is to `null`-ify the relevant field with a sourcemap

```
\DeclareSourcemap{
  \maps[datatype=bibtex]{
    \map{
      \step[fieldset=publisher, null]
    }
  }
}
```

This approach has the (mostly conceptual) advantage that the field is ignored by Biber itself and not passed on to `biblatex` at all. That could be important if the ignored field is used for calculation of `label...` or `extra...` fields (`labelname`, `labeldate`, `extradate`, ...). But of course this also means that the field is completely gone and can't be shown selectively (only for the bibliography or only for citations as would be the case with the `\clearfield` approach).

Answer (score 3):

This does (I think) exactly what you suggest you want.

```
\AtEveryCitekey{\clearlist{publisher}}
\AtEveryBibitem{\clearlist{publisher}}
```

That needs to go in the preamble.