# How to make @bookinbook use short title in bibliography with biblatex-chicago when there are multiple entries pointing to the same @book

Tags: biblatex, biblatex-chicago

Using `biblatex-chicago`, I would like `@bookinbook` to behave analogously to `@incollection` in using the `shorttitle` and just the editor's last name for the `@book` in `crossref` when there are multiple entries pointing to the same book.

## MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[notes]{biblatex-chicago}

\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@book{kotter:schriften.jdam,
    Address = {Berlin},
    Author = {{John of Damascus}},
    Date = {1969/2013},
    Editor = {Kotter, Bonifaz},
    Publisher = {de Gruyter},
    Shorttitle = {Schriften},
    Title = {Die Schriften des Johannes von Damaskos},
    Volumes = {7}}

@bookinbook{jdam:expositio.fidei:kotter1973,
    Crossref = {kotter:schriften.jdam},
    Entrysubtype = {primary},
    Title = {Expositio fidei},
    Volume = {2},
    Year = {1973}}

@bookinbook{jdam:instit.element:dialectica:kotter1969,
    Crossref = {kotter:schriften.jdam},
    Entrysubtype = {primary},
    Title = {Institutio elementaris. Capita philosophica (Dialectica)},
    Volume = {1},
    Year = {1969}}
\end{filecontents*}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}


\begin{document}
\nocite{kotter:schriften.jdam,jdam:instit.element:dialectica:kotter1969,jdam:expositio.fidei:kotter1973}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

## Current output:

[image]

## Desired output:

> John of Damascus. *Die Schriften des Johannes von Damaskos*. Edited by Bonifaz Kotter. 7 vols. Berlin: de Gruyter, 1969–2013.
>
> ——. *Expositio fidei*. In Kotter, *Schriften*, vol. 2. Berlin: de Gruyter, 1973.
>
> ——. *Institutio elementaris. Capita philosophica (Dialectica)*. In Kotter, *Schriften*, vol. 1. Berlin: de Gruyter, 1969.

Comment: There is an option called `booklongxref` which if set to `false` would result in "*Expositio fidei.* In *Schriften*, vol. 2." The output you want is much more tricky because `biblatex` would have to respond dynamically to the data in the parent entry.

Comment: That's perfect! I'm happy with that output too. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`biblatex-chicago` has an option called `booklongxref` that can help you shorten the bibliography entries here.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[notes,booklongxref=false]{biblatex-chicago}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@book{kotter:schriften.jdam,
    Address = {Berlin},
    Author = {{John of Damascus}},
    Date = {1969/2013},
    Editor = {Kotter, Bonifaz},
    Publisher = {de Gruyter},
    Shorttitle = {Schriften},
    Title = {Die Schriften des Johannes von Damaskos},
    Volumes = {7}}

@bookinbook{jdam:expositio.fidei:kotter1973,
    Crossref = {kotter:schriften.jdam},
    Entrysubtype = {primary},
    Title = {Expositio fidei},
    Volume = {2},
    Year = {1973}}

@bookinbook{jdam:instit.element:dialectica:kotter1969,
    Crossref = {kotter:schriften.jdam},
    Entrysubtype = {primary},
    Title = {Institutio elementaris. Capita philosophica (Dialectica)},
    Volume = {1},
    Year = {1969}}
\end{filecontents*}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}


\begin{document}
\nocite{kotter:schriften.jdam,jdam:instit.element:dialectica:kotter1969,jdam:expositio.fidei:kotter1973}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: John of Damascus. Die Schriften des Johannes von Damaskos. Edited by Bonifaz Kotter. 7 vols. Berlin: de Gruyter, 1969–2013.//---. Expositio fidei. In Schriften, vol. 2.//---. Institutio elementaris. Capita philosophica (Dialectica). In Schriften, vol. 1.]

---

The output is not exactly what you had in mind, but hopefully it is close enough.

It seems particularly challenging to me to get the short references in the `@bookinbook` entries to refer to the `editor` of the `@book` work, when the `@book` is primarily associated with its `author`.

The other things can be worked around with some saving and restoring of field values. Internally the short `crossref` is produced by a citation command. Additional information can be passed to that citation command by means of saving fields in macros and restoring the macros later.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[notes,booklongxref=false]{biblatex-chicago}

\usepackage{xpatch}
\xapptobibmacro{crossref:volume+postnote}{%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{saved:publ+loc+year}%
}{}{}

\makeatletter
\xapptobibmacro{xrefprenote}{%
  \iflistundef{publisher}
    {\undef\cbx@incollpublisher}
    {\savelist{publisher}{\cbx@incollpublisher}}%
  \iflistundef{location}
    {\undef\cbx@incolllocation}
    {\savelist{location}{\cbx@incolllocation}}%
  \iffieldundef{year}
    {\undef\cbx@incollyear}
    {\savefield{year}{\cbx@incollyear}}%
  \iffieldundef{endyear}
    {\undef\cbx@incollendyear}
    {\savefield{endyear}{\cbx@incollendyear}}%
}{}{}


\newbibmacro*{saved:publ+loc+year}{%
  \ifboolexpr{
    not test {\iflistequals{publisher}{\cbx@incollpublisher}}
    or
    not test {\iflistequals{location}{\cbx@incolllocation}}
    or
    not test {\iffieldequals{year}{\cbx@incollyear}}
    or
    not test {\iffieldequals{endyear}{\cbx@incollendyear}}
  }
    {\restorelist{publisher}{\cbx@incollpublisher}%
     \restorelist{location}{\cbx@incolllocation}%
     \restorefield{year}{\cbx@incollyear}%
     \restorefield{endyear}{\cbx@incollendyear}%
     \printlist{location}%
     \iflistundef{publisher}%
       {\setunit*{\addcomma\addspace}}%
       {\setunit*{\addcolon\addspace}}%
     \printlist{publisher}%
     \setunit*{\addcomma\addspace}%
     \usebibmacro{date}}
    {}}%
\makeatother

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@book{kotter:schriften.jdam,
    Address = {Berlin},
    Author = {{John of Damascus}},
    Date = {1969/2013},
    Editor = {Kotter, Bonifaz},
    Publisher = {de Gruyter},
    Shorttitle = {Schriften},
    Title = {Die Schriften des Johannes von Damaskos},
    Volumes = {7}}

@bookinbook{jdam:expositio.fidei:kotter1973,
    Crossref = {kotter:schriften.jdam},
    Entrysubtype = {primary},
    Title = {Expositio fidei},
    Volume = {2},
    pages = {2-200},
    Year = {1973}}

@bookinbook{jdam:instit.element:dialectica:kotter1969,
    Crossref = {kotter:schriften.jdam},
    Entrysubtype = {primary},
    Title = {Institutio elementaris. Capita philosophica (Dialectica)},
    Volume = {1},
    pages = {1-100},
    Year = {1969}}
\end{filecontents*}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}


\begin{document}
\nocite{kotter:schriften.jdam,jdam:instit.element:dialectica:kotter1969,jdam:expositio.fidei:kotter1973}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: John of Damascus. Die Schriften des Johannes von Damaskos. Edited by Bonifaz Kotter. 7 vols. Berlin: de Gruyter, 1969–2013.//. Expositio fidei. In Schriften, 2:2–200. Berlin: de Gruyter, 1973.//. Institutio elementaris. Capita philosophica (Dialectica). In Schriften, 1:1–100. Berlin: de Gruyter, 1969.]

Comment: Even better, thank you again. Thinking about it, it is probably clearer (from a human perspective too!) not to carry over the editor from the parent entry. That also might make it possible to have individual volumes edited by different editors -- as indeed is the case for this multivolume work. But perhaps that should be a separate question...

Comment: @AlexRoberts If the editor is important it might make sense to carry it over, but have it mentioned after the `shorttitle` (as in the `@book` entry itself). Unfortunately, that would also be tricky to pull off here, especially seeing that you probably don't want the editor mentioned for all works, but only for a certain subclass of works where the editor has a more important role than usual.

Comment: I just noticed that when the publisher is missing (or when combined with [code that omits the publisher](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/468161/suppressing-publisher-in-notes-using-biblatex-chicago)), the `address` and `year` are separated by a colon (Berlin: 1973) rather than a comma (Berlin, 1973).

Comment: @AlexRoberts That was an embarrassing copy-and-paste error. I forgot to include one line (`\iflistundef{publisher}%`) from the original `publ+loc+year` macro. Thanks for spotting that. Should be fixed now.

Comment: Yes, it works now -- thank you!